# How can I use AES to encrypt a single block?

Tags: .net, cryptography

I want to use AES inside another crypto algorithm, and as such I need to encrypt single 128 bit blocks at a time inside a for loop.

However the examples on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) which show the uses of some of the cryptography classes like RijndaelManaged make use of IO streams along with ICryptoTransform to transform the entire plaintext directly to ciphertext.

But I'm thinking this might be ok for an entire long plaintext, however if I'm only working on individual blocks inside a for loop, would using those three streams cause unnecessary overhead?  Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [blog post](http://www.martani.net/2012/09/single-block-aes-encryptiondecryption.html)

> "...used the TransformBlock method of the ICryptoTransform interface.
>   This method does exactly one block transformation of the underlying
>   block cipher (AES in our case), there is no explicit padding involved
>   nor chaining in the case of CBC.  To get a consistent AES block encryption/decryption, it was mandatory to eliminate the XOR with the Initial Vector (IV). This can be achieved whether by using the ECB mode or using the CBC mode with an initial IV = 0^{128}"

```
private static byte[] AES_encrypt_block(byte[] plainText, byte[] Key)
{
    byte[] output_buffer = new byte[plainText.Length];

    using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
    {
        //If CBC, must initialize IV = O_{128}
        //aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        //aesAlg.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
        aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        aesAlg.Key = Key;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        encryptor.TransformBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length, output_buffer, 0);
    }

    return output_buffer;
}

private static byte[] AES_Decrypt_block(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key)
{
    // Declare the string used to hold the decrypted text. 
    byte[] output_buffer = new byte[cipherText.Length];

    using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
    {
        //If CBC, must initialize IV = O_{128}
        //aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        //aesAlg.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
        aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        aesAlg.Key = Key;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        decryptor.TransformBlock(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length, output_buffer, 0);
    }

    return output_buffer;
}
```